# How can I create this simple form example in HTML?

Tags: html, css

I'm a developer with limited HTML/CSS design experience. I have been stuck trying to create this simple form for over an hour so I'm giving up and asking for help.

[image: Simple Form Example]

I tried doing something like this:

```
<ul>
    <li><label>Name:</label><span class="line">&nbsp</span></li>
    ...
</ul>

li label {
    display: inline-block;
}

li span {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
```

I have no idea how I can express that I want the span to take up 100% of the width between the label and the containing div.

I would like the rendered HTML to look exactly like my example image. That is, the entire list item should not be underlined, only the space where the customer is to fill in the information.

Please let me know how I can achieve this. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here's a simple example](http://jsfiddle.net/ASJJw/1/) of what you want to do. Basically, you give the `li` a bottom border, and overlap it with the `label`'s border to cover up the black line.

```
li
{
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    width: 250px;
}

label
{
    border-bottom: 2px solid white;
    padding-right: 5px;
}
```

---

I'm not sure how cross browser the above solution is, so you might want to use a few extra directives, [just in case](http://jsfiddle.net/ASJJw/3/) (untested):

```
li
{
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    width: 250px;
}

label
{
    background: white;
    position: relative;
    border-bottom: 2px solid white;
    padding-right: 5px;
}
```

---

**Cross browser solution** (as far as I can tell):

Thanks to @Joseph, there's [this solution](http://jsfiddle.net/ASJJw/2/) to a thin line being displayed under the label.

Comment: seems to have an issue with chrome :(

Comment: sorry... 3 comments :( but http://jsfiddle.net/ASJJw/2/ might work cross browser.

Comment: I know it's cheating, but giving the `li` a 1px bottom border fixes it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I think I found a cross-browser way of doing it without using over-lapping borders!

Comment: No problem. The most important part is that you found an answer that works!

Comment: .... and the proprietary HTML > PDF renderer that I am using doesn't like the table-cell solution so I am using this and it works well. Thanks!

Comment: No problem. Teamwork: 1, stuggling with it for ages: 0. If you use PHP, there are a few libraries for messing about with PDFs.

Answer (score 2):

### EDIT

meh... I like [my adaptation of JamWaffles' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7408557/how-can-i-create-this-simple-form-example-in-html/7408878#answer-7408884) better (comments).  He should get the credit. :P

---

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xLQ9B/)**

Here's a very hackish way of doing it :P

#### HTML

```
<ul>
    <li><label>Name:</label></li>
    <li><label>Address:</label></li>
    <li><label>City:</label></li>
    <li><label>State:</label></li>
    <li><label>Zip:</label></li>
</ul>
```

#### CSS

```
li label {
    margin-bottom:-1px;
    display: inline-block;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
    padding-right:10px;
}

li {
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
```

Comment: Nice, but why do you need the `inline-block` directives? The `label` is inline by default, and the `li`s are on separate lines regardless of how long they are.

Comment: @JamWaffles death by copy and paste. :P  I just pasted in the code supplied by the PO so some of it is superfluous.

Comment: Ah. No worries \*pulls out defibrilator\*. Also, thanks for the citation.

Answer (score 2):

OK I really hate answering my own question but this seems like the least-hackish way of achieving this result. I'll let the votes decide. Thanks again for all the help. I can't believe how long it took me to figure this out!

[Solution using display:table-cell](http://jsfiddle.net/GqzAk/)

```
li label {
    display: table-cell;
}

li span {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}

<ul>
    <li><label>Name:</label><span></span></li>
    <li><label>Address:</label><span></span></li>
    <li><label>City:</label><span></span></li>
    <li><label>State:</label><span></span></li>
    <li><label>Zip:</label><span></span></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Nice solution! but just as a point of interest, IE < 8 doesn't support `display:table-cell` http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html#t06 :S

Answer (score 0):

add a class to the span that you want to have a border-bottom

example

```
li span.underline {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
```

Comment: How is this different than the example that I gave that didn't work?

Answer (score 0):

Interesting concept. I'd tackle it something like this:

```
<style type="text/css">
    input.line {
        border: 0;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    }
</style>

<ul><li><label for="name">Name: </label><input class="line" name="name" /></li><br />
<li><label for="address">Address: </label><input class="line" name="address" /></li><br />
<li><label for="city">City: </label><input class="line" name="city" /></li><br />
<li><label for="state">State: </label><input class="line" name="state" /></li><br />
<li><label for="zip">ZIP: </label><input class="line" name="zip" /></li></ul><br />
```

**Edit** This is code for a functional form that you can TYPE things into, I didn't realize you just wanted the underline. Either way, this solution should work for both.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. And yes, this is actually going to be printed out so it doesn't matter if there are actual input elements or not. Anyway, I tried your example and the problem is that all the input boxes, and therefore the bottom borders, are the same width. I would like the HTML to look just like my picture example. That is, I would like the lines to go from the label and extend out to to the containing div so that the total width of each label and line is the same.

Answer (score 0):

[Here's a solution](http://jsfiddle.net/cdeszaq/Upa4f/23/):

html:

```
<ul>
    <li><span class="label">Name:</span><span class="line name"></span></li>
    <li><span class="label">Address:</span><span class="line address"></span></li>
    <li><span class="label">City:</span><span class="line city"></span></li>
    <li><span class="label">State:</span><span class="line state"></span></li>
    <li><span class="label">Zip:</span><span class="line zip"></span></li>
</ul>
```

css:

```
ul {width: 300px;}

.line {
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    border-bottom: 2px solid black;
    margin-left: 5px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: -5px;
}

.label {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: white;
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding-right: 5px;
}


li span {font-family: sans-serif;}

li {line-height: 1.3em;}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I really want to do this without having to set everything manually to be pixel-perfect.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, this is another way to do it: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/7SFDV/.

The only real difference this has (over your answer) is that it will work in IE7, which is probably not relevant to you. I have no idea if it will work with your "proprietary HTML > PDF renderer".

```
li {
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 8px 0
}
li label {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 3px
}
li span {
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
    line-height: 1.1
}
```